# Why this Jquery slideToggle not working on phone?

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

http://lapan.com.ba/denisa-daca-ar-avea-videoclip-original-manele-noi-august-2016/

Jquery is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$('.show-hide').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.entry-content').slideToggle();
    $(this).text( $(this).text() == 'Read More' ? "Show Less" : "Read More");
});
});
</script>
```

It is button Opis...3rd green under video.

```
<div class="under-video" style="">
<input style="
    float: right;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;"
type="button" value="Opis" class='show-hide' value='hide/show'>...
```

Comment: Hi @Mr.Meme, welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question already shows part of your current code, but I believe it still leaves some room for confusion. Do you see any error messages on `console`? It happens on every phone browser? More details you share, more chance someone helps.

Comment: Works on the phone but had to wait for the page to fully load. I guess you have some synchronous scripts that are blocking it. You should try to defer and async your scripts.